# implementing the NWalign.java alignment script for needleman wunsch algorithm

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to run the *NWaling.java* file found [here](http://www.google.com.lb/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CD0QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Feagle.fish.washington.edu%2Fwhale%2Ffish546%2FTrinity_r2013-08-14_analysis1-2014-02-08-20-44-13.233%2Fbin%2Ftrinityrnaseq_r2013_08_14%2FButterfly%2Fsrc%2Fsrc%2FNWalign.java&ei=TVQcVMTDMOHQ7AafqoGYCA&usg=AFQjCNGlsYOZEzAsPbGrzdD3T_VzSWPwqQ&bvm=bv.75774317,d.ZGU&cad=rja). the code present at the link that I mentioned makes use of the jaligner library. I have downloaded this Java package from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaligner/files/jaligner/). inside the zip folder there is a JAR file. I'm developing the code using eclipse. whenever  I add this JAR file to the code there are some classes missing for example:

```
import jaligner.NeedlemanWunschGotoh;
```

&

```
import jaligner.matrix.MatrixGenerator;
```

also in the entire zipped folder there isn't any pom.xml file to allow me to import the entire folder as a maven project to eclipse. can somenone suggest me how to import this jaligner library and use it in eclipse? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a community implementation of the *jaligner* algorithm from [here](https://github.com/ahmedmoustafa/JAligner/archive/master.zip).

Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/macmanes/trinityrnaseq/tree/master/Butterfly/src/src) sources where you may perhaps find all the searched artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The full Eclipse project with the `NWalign.java` can be found [here](http://eagle.fish.washington.edu/whale/index.php?dir=fish546/Trinity_r2013-08-14_analysis1-2014-02-08-20-44-13.233/bin/trinityrnaseq_r2013_08_14/Butterfly/src/) including [.classpath](http://eagle.fish.washington.edu/whale/fish546/Trinity_r2013-08-14_analysis1-2014-02-08-20-44-13.233/bin/trinityrnaseq_r2013_08_14/Butterfly/src/.classpath) file with all dependencies listed there.